# Need help in setting production environment for 300 million records elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I am new to elastic search. I am doing POC on set-up production environment. I need help to do this.

1) What are the production parameters we need to consider when setting the environment ?

3) what are all the watermark need to set-up production ready environment ?

There are two process running live server(improve performance Ex: performance 20 to 40 milliseconds), Batch process server (improve throughput. Ex: In 1 hour 1 server will serve 200 transaction).

live server will have 8 dedicated server nodes. Batch Process will have 12 servers.

How to distribute request between live server and Batch node to not compromise live server performance while Batch in progress. How to scale up application without performance compromise.

Live server transaction 250K/hour in single server (We have 8 Online servers)
Batch process 1MN/hour in single server ( we have 8 Batch servers)

What are all the requirements needed for the above scenario for setting production environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would say definitely read the Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide chapter on Production Deployment:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/deploy.html

There are far too many factors that contribute to needed settings and deployment topology to provide an exhaustive answer. Indexing and serving 300 million tweets is a lot different than 300 million science papers. Fulltext search is very different from numeric aggregations and analytics. Really the only way to know for sure is for you to test it (and monitor it!), using as close to real data and access patterns as you can.

Also, I'm a little bit confused between your "batch" and "live" servers, but you have several options for mixed workloads. For the best isolation, use two completely separate clusters. Alternatively, if you have separate indices for "batch" and "live" but want to be able to move an index from "live" to "batch", you can use [Shard Allocation Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/shard-allocation-filtering.html) to control which servers each indices' shards go on. This will separate the data, and in many scenarios this is sufficient. The nice thing is those rules can be changed dynamically and ES will move around your shards to match.

Depending on your workloads, the client (coordinator) role might have troubles if a "live" request hits a "batch" client node, and in this case it can be useful to have one or more client only (no data) nodes allocated to just serving the "live" requests (direct your "live" application to these nodes), and another allocated to just serving the "batch" requests (direct your "batch" application to these nodes). Your options here depend on the type of client also.

Unfortunately your question is pretty generic, and the answer has to be "test it with your specific workload"

Comment: live server is consider here as an online application search request and batch process is consider as an bulk request and request would be in file format below is the sample setup we have for testing for this we need a suggestion in production File System
Store Size: 85.0GB 85.4GB
Documents: 336,954,885 336,954,885
Index Activity
Search - Query: 14.83ms 14msSearch - Fetch: 1.48ms 1.51ms
Refresh: 2.14ms 41.04ms
Memory
Heap Size: 2.6 gb 2.8 gb
% Heap Used: 44.2% 61.2%